# simple regular expression in php to check for possible values for a variable

Tags: php, regex, if-statement

There are are a few finite values that my variable `$_GET['action']` can take, either "new", "edit", or "delete".

I want to sanitize my input for security and make sure the variable is only one of those above values, how can I do that using regular expressions?

I don't want to go and say:

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && ($_GET['action'] == 'new' || $_GET['action'] == 'edit' || $_GET['action'] == 'delete'))
```

Comment: I recommend to make a function of it. This way you are more flexible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not use a regex for this. Use [`in_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check a value against a *white list*:

```
if(!in_array($_GET, array("new", "edit", "delete"), TRUE)) {
    die('Error!');
}
```

Comment: why? would regex be slower?

Comment: I expect a regex is much slower. Will test, give me a minute

Comment: Is the `strict` flag necessary?

Comment: @kingkero Good question! :) In this special case: not. However, I suggested it in the example, as the *real* data might be sensitive for it

Comment: @user961627 My little test showed me that `in_array()` is ~ `30%` faster then `preg_match()`

Answer (score 2):

A `switch` is probably the best solution, but seeing nothing of your code makes it hard to tell. The regex you are searching for looks like the following

```
/^(new|edit|delete)$/i
```

Described in words it checks if between the beginning and the end of the line there is one of the three possibilities (case insensitive)

Comment: agree with this, regex should be more of a pattern recongition than a simple value checker

Answer (score 2):

It's simple just do:

```
if( isset($_GET['action']) && preg_match("/^(new|edit|delete)$/i", $_GET['action']))
     doSomething();
```

Answer (score 1):

this should help

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && in_array($_GET['action'], array('new', 'edit', 'delete')))
```

or

```
$allowed_methods = array('new', 'edit', 'delete');
if(isset($_GET['action']) && in_array($_GET['action'], $allowed_methods))
```

Answer (score 1):

Match them using the or (|) operator

```
if (preg_match("/^(new|edit|delete)$/", $_GET['action'])) { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])){
  switch($_GET['action']){
    case 'edit':
        //etc...
        break;
    case 'new':
        //etc...
        break;
    case 'delete':
        //etc...
        break;
    default:
        echo 'No valid actions';
  }
}
```

Use the switch for a good action management

Comment: Then you need to change your code twice if you want to add/remove actions

Comment: @kingkero in effects was useless the first control, the switch is enough